# Navigate directly to GPS location

Tags: android, gps, maps

Is there any way (other than google.navitation intent, which only works with Google Maps) for any offline GPS app to request from a third party app a navigation to a location?

I mean straight navigation, not showing the point in the map and then pressing "navigate"; what I want is the same functionality the google.navigation intent provides but with any other GPS app that supports offline maps.

Comment: When you contacted the developers of "any other GPS app that supports offline maps", and asked them if they have an API for their Android app, what did they tell you?

Comment: Well, you can interpret my question as "is there any offline GPS app that provides an API?" instead of making sarcastic remarks.

Comment: My point is that there are only a few offline GPS apps for Android. You can find them easily enough through the Play Store. The Play Store listings have links to their respective Web sites. If they have a documented and supported API, that information should appear on their Web sites. Hence, you can get the answer to your question without having to wait for some response here. Also, note that there is no documented and supported API for the navigation portion of the Google Maps app.